# How do I change the sender name of a PHP email?

Tags: php, email

I have a script that sends an email, but instead of the sender name being "admin@foo.bar", I want it to say "Foobar Admin". How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this??

```
$email_from = $full_name.'<'.$email_from.'>';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

for reference use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

Use this;

```
<?php
$to      = 'to@mail.com';
$subject = 'Your subject';
$message = 'Your message';
$headers = 'From: Foobar Admin<admin@foo.bar>' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: admin@foo.bar' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mail("recipient@aol.com","subject","message","From:Foobar Admin<foobar@admin.com>");
```